# I can't figure out why I get a blank output file

Tags: python, excel, csv

```
import csv
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

#CREATE CSV FILE

outfile = open("./output.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

#IMPORT MATCHES

import csv
with open('matches.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    matches = list(reader)

for id in matches:
    id = str(id)
    id = re.sub("[^0-9]","",id)
    url = 'http://www.virtualpronetwork.com/apps/fvpaa/matches/match_report/' + id
    print (url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
#GET TEAMS AND SCORES

score = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"col-md-5 center"})

    team_home = score[0]
    team_home = str(team_home)
    team_home = re.search('title="(.*)" />',team_home)
    team_home = team_home.group(1)

    team_away = score[1]
    team_away = str(team_away)
    team_away = re.search('title="(.*)" />',team_away)
    team_away = team_away.group(1)

    goals_home = score[2]
    goals_home = str(goals_home)
    goals_home = re.sub('</h2></div>','',goals_home)
    goals_home = re.sub('<div class="col-md-5 center"><h2>','',goals_home)

    goals_away = score[3]
    goals_away = str(goals_away)
    goals_away = re.sub('</h2></div>','',goals_away)
    goals_away = re.sub('<div class="col-md-5 center"><h2>','',goals_away)
#GET HOME STATS

tables = soup.findChildren('table')

    stats_home = tables[0]
    list_of_rows_home = []
    for row in stats_home.findChildren('tr')[1:]:
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[0]:
            text = cell.text
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[1]:
            text = cell.text
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[2:]:
            list_of_cells.append(cell)
        list_of_rows_home.append(list_of_cells) 

    for i in range(len(list_of_rows_home)):
        row = list_of_rows_home[i]
        cell = list_of_rows_home[i][2]
        cell = str(cell)
        goal = re.findall('goal',cell)
        goal = goal.count('goal')
        goal = goal / 2
        assist = re.findall('assist',cell)
        assist = assist.count('assist')
        assist = assist / 2
        motm = re.findall('motm',cell)
        motm = motm.count('motm')
        row.append(goal)
        row.append(assist)
        row.append(motm)

    for row in list_of_rows_home:
        del row[2]

    for i in range(len(list_of_rows_home)):
        row = list_of_rows_home[i]
        row.append(team_home)
        row.append(goals_home)
        row.append(team_away)
        row.append(goals_away)  

#GET AWAY STATS
stats_away = tables[1]
    list_of_rows_away = []
    for row in stats_away.findChildren('tr')[1:]:
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[0]:
            text = cell.text
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[1]:
            text = cell.text
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        for cell in row.findChildren('td')[2:]:
            list_of_cells.append(cell)
        list_of_rows_away.append(list_of_cells)

    for i in range(len(list_of_rows_away)):
        row = list_of_rows_away[i]
        cell = list_of_rows_away[i][2]
        cell = str(cell)
        goal = re.findall('goal',cell)
        goal = goal.count('goal')
        goal = goal / 2
        assist = re.findall('assist',cell)
        assist = assist.count('assist')
        assist = assist / 2
        motm = re.findall('motm',cell)
        motm = motm.count('motm')
        row.append(goal)
        row.append(assist)
        row.append(motm)

    for row in list_of_rows_away:
        del row[2]

    for i in range(len(list_of_rows_away)):
        row = list_of_rows_away[i]
        row.append(team_away)
        row.append(goals_away)
        row.append(team_home)
        row.append(goals_home)
#COMPILE INTO ONE TABLE
list_of_rows = list_of_rows_home + list_of_rows_away
#WRITE TO CSV
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

My input file is a basic excel file with the match id's all lined up in column one of the excel file. When it creates the output file, it's blank. I am not getting any error messages either.

Comment: I also have my input and script file in the desktop folder on my PC.

Comment: This is where I would start throwing in print statements to see if the output actually exists. The first one I would try would be right before you try to write the output. Ex: `print(list_of_rows)`

Comment: Thank you Chathan, I actually do not get anything from that print statement so I'm assuming that the output doesn't exist. I'm not sure why it does not exist though unless something is wrong with my installation of beautifulsoup or requests (which were the only things I installed when making this script).

Comment: In that case I would keep moving higher in your script and seeing which values aren't output as you would expect them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `regex` search, so perhaps change it to:

```
team_home = re.search('title="(.*)"',team_home)
team_home = team_home.group(1)
```

**Alternative**:

```
team_home = re.search('title="(.*)"/>',team_home)
team_home = team_home.group(1)
```

The `/>` is not needed, and this essentially makes **title=""** not match for group(1), which in turn creates an Attribute Error, and the script stops. If you want to include `/>` then remove the space in your regex pattern, since that is ultimately what kills it.